# how to remove root user from gmail message sent through phpmailer

Tags: php

I manage to sent message to my gmail account using phpmailer library through local 
host in my xampp but the message has 'root user' shown instead of the gmail account set to $mail->SetFrom how to remove this 'root user' and show the appropriate name.

```
<?php
$mail = new PHPMailer();

$mail->IsSMTP();  // telling the class to use SMTP 
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
$mail->Mailer     = "smtp";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";
$mail->Username   = "georgediamei1234@gmail.com";
$mail->Password   = "password";
$mail->Host       = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com'; // SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 465;
$mail->FromName   ='georgediamei1234@gmail.com';

$mail->AddAddress("nowtonkhurai@gmail.com");

$mail->Subject  = "";
$mail->Body     = "Hello, <b>Is photo attached</b>!\n\n This message uses                HTML entities!";
$mail->addStringAttachment("$string","08DsAlg.pdf", "base64","application/pdf");

if($mail->send()) {
    echo "Email sent";
} else {
    echo 'Not send '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
?>
```

Comment: Where's your code mate, This sets the email from and sender name in php Mailer 5.2,        $mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

Comment: Thanks for reminding, i forgot that actually.

Comment: But there is a  minor problem in a reply box in gmail, there are two reciver e-mail id like this  "georgediamei1234@gmail.com(georgediamei1234@gmail.com)" .How do i remove the second one

Answer (score 2):

```
$mail->setFrom('from@example.com', 'Mailer');
```

I also got stumbled with that root problem. You have to set a mail id and a name in setFrom property. As the question was asked 2 years ago it might not be helpful to you but it might help others who get stuck with the same stuff.

Answer (score 0):

use both function for name and email address like this :

```
$mail->From = "from@example.com";
$mail->FromName = "Mailer";
```